# Dialog box not being shown

Tags: android, dialog

I have written the code to show a custom dialog box. The background is becoming transparent as is written in the code but the dialog box is not appearing.

```
    protected void initiatedialog(View view) {

    final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(PostsActivity.this);
    dialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    dialog.setContentView(R.layout.popup);

    dialog.getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(android.graphics.Color.TRANSPARENT));
    WindowManager.LayoutParams lp = new WindowManager.LayoutParams();
    lp.copyFrom(dialog.getWindow().getAttributes());
    lp.width = Math.round((width * 10) / 15);
    lp.height = Math.round(height / 3);
    dialog.getWindow().setAttributes(lp);
    final EditText etPostContent = (EditText) dialog.findViewById(R.id.etPostContent);
    Button bAddPost = (Button) dialog.findViewById(R.id.bAddPost);


    bAddPost.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
           //something
         dialog.dismiss();
        }
    });
    dialog.show();
}
```

Here is the xml file for the dialog box customisation.

popup.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"

    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
   android:gravity="center"
    android:background="@drawable/popup_background">
    <EditText
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="3"
        android:id="@+id/etButton"
        android:hint="Write.."/>
    <Button
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/bAdd"
        android:layout_weight="7"
        android:text="Button"/>
```

Comment: Try using Alert dialog box

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, first of all - it's working on my phone (Android 4.0.3).
Since I don't know some of your variables/drawables, I'll put slightly changed code and describe a difference.
**1. Popup.xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"

    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:gravity="center">
    <EditText
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="3"
        android:id="@+id/etPostContent"
        android:hint="Write.."/>
    <Button
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/bAddPost"
        android:layout_weight="7"
        android:text="Button"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

I don't know your `android:background="@drawable/popup_background"` - firstly try to remove this line and see if problem remains.
Also I changed ids of views - because you point another names in your Java file.
**2. MainActivity (with imports).**

```
import android.app.Dialog;
import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.drawable.ColorDrawable;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.Window;
import android.view.WindowManager;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        initiatedialog(null);
    }


    protected void initiatedialog(View view) {

        final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(MainActivity.this);
        dialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        dialog.setContentView(R.layout.popup);

        dialog.getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(android.graphics.Color.TRANSPARENT));
        WindowManager.LayoutParams lp = new WindowManager.LayoutParams();
        lp.copyFrom(dialog.getWindow().getAttributes());

        int width = ((WindowManager) getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE)).getDefaultDisplay().getWidth();
        int height = ((WindowManager) getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE)).getDefaultDisplay().getHeight();
        lp.width = Math.round((width * 10) / 15);
        lp.height = Math.round(height / 3);
        dialog.getWindow().setAttributes(lp);
        final EditText etPostContent = (EditText) dialog.findViewById(R.id.etPostContent);
        Button bAddPost = (Button) dialog.findViewById(R.id.bAddPost);

        bAddPost.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                //something
                dialog.dismiss();
            }
        });
        dialog.show();
    }
}
```

A bit comment - I don't know, what your width and height are - so I took window width and height;
 also please check imports.

Please see the result:
[image]

**PS. A little tip** - it you wish `layout_weight` xml attribute be working - you should set `layout_width = "0dp"`. Try and see changed result. See it:
[image]

Please make abovementioned changes and see what happenes. Thanks.

Comment: Nothing helped. The dialog box is still not appearing.

Comment: Sorry! It worked. I had forgotten to add a line. Thank you so much for the help.